# JavaScript - How to evaluate an EL with a JS variable inside?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, jsp, el

**Problem**

I have a Java list (and I am using Java Server Pages) and I want to iterate over each element of the list in JS (so the index is the JS variable).

Obviously I cannot set the index as a variable and do this :

`var v = '${object.list[' + index + '].value}'`

Instead, I have to write a specific EL for each possible index.

`${object.list[0].value}
${object.list[1].value}
...`

This is very redundant. I only have a list of 4 elements so I can manage, but if it was 100...

**Solution ?**

So far I can store the EL as a string, like this :

`var v = "$" + "{object.list[" + index + "].value}"`

Now, can you tell me if I have any means to evaluate this string as an EL ? Like using the eval() function for example (which does not work).

Comment: What is `${…}`?

Comment: Have you tried simply `var v = ${object.list[index].value}`? Don't fool around with strings when you don't have to.

Comment: "*I have a Java list*" - sounds like you want to serialise that to a JSON array, and then iterate that in a normal JS loop.

Comment: ${…} is the syntax for an EL with Java Server Pages.

I tried but it does not work.

Indeed I could use a JSON array but I really don't want to add something else. I feel like there must be a way to achieve this simply. Or at least it should.

Comment: it is also a valid interpolation in JS template strings. You don't state that you are dealing with jsp in your question...

Comment: I edited my post concerning JSP. Didn't know it was relevant.